# Animation deflating

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, keyframes

Hello blender community

i was trying out a few things for a simple animation
and wanted to copy over a keyframe and found that the animation suddenly 
deflates. as hilarious as it is it makes me wonder why that is.
i tried to copy the first keyframe with ctr c in the dopesheet to make it also be the last
frame so i can make it smooth. i put it on the last spot and deleted the one
that was in the row before (because it was unsmooth)
as i read it is supposed to work normally and i believe i have used it before i am now fairly intrigued and confused. i would appreciate if someone can enlighten me.

[here is the link to the deflation](https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T034HDMRC-FC1ACU2NB/2018-07-31_20-34-52.gif)

thank you everyone in advance for your thoughts!

Comment: Please edit your question and include the gif in your post. I don't have an active slack account and can't view your animation.

Comment: @Marie to access the link one should have account on slack. Not good. Use internal image here on BSE (2MB limit) or some other free sharing site.

Comment: ive tried to show it directly. either the format was not supported or the file is to big and i dont know how to make a gif smaller. linking it gave me the website has denied the request.

Comment: In the absence of anything much to go on, are you padlocking out all dopesheet strips (at the left) except the destination strip?  It's a precaution I take because all too often I've dumped copies of keyframes somewhere I hadn't intended.

As a security blanket, I also place the cursor into the destination strip and highlite that strip.  

The timeline cursor is also set to where the keyframe is to be pasted to.  
You could also try pasting to a point beyond the last keyframe at the destination, drag them back after.
Hope this helps...